# Selenium Programming: what is the short cut that allow you to see the element names for your browser

Tags: java, selenium, element

Ok, so you know you want to go to google.com, and you want to type something into the search box.

How can you find out the name of the element to use in your code?
Is there something that allows you to check the browser you are using to find the element names?
Is this different for `IE` vs. `Chrome` vs. `Firefox` vs. `Edge`.

```
WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
```

I am programming in Java

Comment: This is very unclear. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok, I thought I was on the right track but maybe I'm not.  Here's what I am trying to do:   Go to Google.Com, Locate the search Box, Type something inside of it, and hit the Google Search button.    Now, my assumption is that you have to find out what the button is named.  You have to find out what the search text box is called.  That's how you tell it which box to go to, to type in the text you want.  So there must be a way to examine the elements on the web page to be able to see the name of the object you are interested in.  That's how I thought it worked.  Does this make sense or I'm off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the browser inspector by clicking `F12` or by right click on the item you want to find -> choose inspect. You will get this

[image]

The element you are looking for will be opened highlighted in the middle of the screen. You can also check your selectors in the `console` tab as in the examole in the picture.

Comment: thanks.................!